# How to find a combination of elements that sum up just above threshold value

Tags: algorithm, optimization, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm, knapsack-problem

I have a problem statement which says: if you have an array of elements {x1,x2,x3,...x10}, find the combination of elements such that it just sums up above a threshold value (say the threshold value is 100).

So if there exists a combination like `x2+x5+x8 = 105`, `x3+x5+x8=103`, and `x4+x5 = 101`, then the algorithm should output X4, X5.

The knapsack algorithm emits a value that is near but on the lesser side of the threshold (which is 100 here). I want the opposite, that is the smallest sum of selected elements that is greater than 100.

Is there any set of algorithms or any special case of any algorithm which might solve this problem?

Comment: You could try a variation of the coin change algorithm. Optimized Coin change can be used to find the individual sums of all subsets of an array of numbers in O(n) space. But keeping track of which subset formed that particular sum is tricky. See the simplified version of the algorithm [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start out by noting that you are asking for the smallest value strictly greater than some target. In general "strictly greater than" and "strictly less than" constraints are much harder than "greater than or equal to" or "less than or equal to" constraints. If you have all integer values, then you could simply translate your constraint "the sum exceeds 100" to "the sum is greater than or equal to 101". I'll assume that you've made such a transformation for the rest of the problem.

One approach would be to treat this as an integer optimization problem, in which the binary decision variable `y_i` for each number is whether or not we include it. Then our goal is to minimize the sum of the numbers, which can be modeled as:

```
min x_1*y_1 + x_2*y_2 + ... + x_n*y_n
```

The constraint in this case is that the sum of the numbers is at least 100:

```
x_1*y_1 + x_2*y_2 + ... + x_n*y_n >= 100
```

In general this is a hard problem (note that it is at least as hard as the subset sum problem, which is NP-complete). However modern optimization solvers may be efficient enough for your problem instances.

To test the scalability of a free solver for this problem, consider the following implementation with the `lpSolve` package in R (it returns the selected subset if the problem is feasible and `NA` otherwise):

```
library(lpSolve)
min.subset <- function(x, min.sum) {
  mod <- lp("min", x, matrix(x, nrow=1), ">=", min.sum, all.bin=TRUE)
  if (mod$status == 0) {
    which(mod$solution >= 0.999)
  } else {
    NA
  }
}
min.subset(1:10, 43.5)
# [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
min.subset(1:10, 88)
# [1] NA
```

To test the scalability, I'll select `n` elements randomly from `[1, 2, ..., 1000]`, setting the target sum to be half the sum of the elements. The runtimes were:

- With `n=100`, it ran in 0.01 seconds
- With `n=1000`, it ran in 0.1 seconds
- With `n=10000`, it ran in 8.7 seconds

It appears you can solve this problem for more than 10k elements (with the selected distribution) without too many computational challenges. If your problem is too big for the free solver I've used here, you might consider Gurobi or cplex, two commercial solvers that are free for academic use but otherwise not free.

Comment: hey @Josiber , I am trying to implement it in java, if you can provide any sudo code or video tutorial link of your implementation would really help full, again thanks for your efforts.!!!!

Comment: @ArghoChatterjee I would encourage you to try implementing it yourself and to post a new question is you run into any implementation issues.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `X` is the sum of all `x_i`. Then equivalently, you are asking for a minimum subset of your `x_i` that sum up to at most `X - 100` (as the complement of these `x_i` will be the optimum solution to your problem). So all Knapsack theory can be applied here.

In practice (really large instances), I'd suggest [this](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=780578) form of Nemhauser-Ullman generalization which can solve instances with millions of objects.